# Our Twitter profile's icon is not high enough quality

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, twitter

Our [Twitter profile image](https://twitter.com/#!/TheArqade) is a bit blurry.

[image]

Looks like a bad scale operation, can we have a crisper one?

Comment: Obviously. The source image is 120×120 and Twitter uses 128×128 and 48×48 sizes. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated the twitter avatar to higher res. Also created a header image for the account as well.

https://twitter.com/TheArqade